# Does a numeric field always use the same disk space?

Tags: mysql, datatypes, disk-space

When you have a numeric field in MySQL(MYISAM) (E.g. Integer) will it always use the same disk space, no matter what number is actually stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's integers take 4 bytes, regardless of the value you store.  ([Data storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html))

[MyISAM supports compression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-storage-engine.html), but only with a compressed row format, which makes the table read-only. I don't think I've ever worked on an application where a read-only table was appropriate.